# wordpress wp-admin login doesnt work after wp-config edit

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I made a mistake by erroneously changing the site URL in general settings in Wordpress.

My website pages would load but I got a redirect loop back when trying to login on the wp-admin page.

To fix this I accessed my wp-config.php via SSH and added the following:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://swsportpsychology.co.uk');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://swsportpsychology.co.uk');
```

Now my website still loads as before but the wp-admin page will not load at all, so I cant login and it says cant access server.

How should I fix this? Any ideas?

**Update**

I have also added this to my themes functions.php:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://swsportpsychology.co.uk');
update_option('home','http://swsportpsychology.co.uk');
```

But still no fix.

Comment: Try to re-migrated your database to correct url.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `functions.php` in your theme:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://swsportpsychology.co.uk');
update_option('home','http://swsportpsychology.co.uk');
```